# Program to demonstrate TDD + Mocking

Tags: mocking, tdd, easymock

I have to write a program that takes an Integer and converts it into its English word version.

For example:

```
Input:  21
Output: twenty one
Input:  110 
Output: one hundred and ten
```

I need the program to demonstrate TDD so I want to use mocking.

I have written a class that has a function that does the conversion (based on 2 arrays of English words). What I need now to design the program in such a way that I can demonstrate with Easymock.

Therefore, I need create an interface to be the subject of my mock. Can anyone give me any pointers on how I would design my program?

Would this be suitable?

1. Write a `Converter` class that has a reference to an interface called `ConverterInterface`. I could then mock the interface and set it into my `Converter` class.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Mocking is typically used to simulate something else.  What are you trying to simulate?  The output mechanism?

Comment: If you want to demonstrate TDD, you should throw out your code and start writing tests.

Comment: @vaughan: That's my problem. My program can easily be written without mocking but I need to write it in a way as to demonstrate mocking. Therefore, I need to design it as such. The design will obviously be convoluted but the exercise is to demonstrate mocking.

Comment: So basically, what I'm asking is it possible to demonstrate mocking with this trivial little program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can demonstrate TDD without mocking. In fact, mocking can confuse people that are new to TDD. I would simply start by test driving the functionality you are trying to develop, and then worry about mocking later. Let's assume you've test driven the numeric to English converter (which it doesn't appear you have done yet based on your description) and you have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class NumberConverterTest { ... }

public class NumberConverter {
  public String toEnglish(int number) { ... }
}
```

You are likely to also have some sort of main class:

```
public class NumberConverterMain {
  public void main(String[] args) {
    NumberConverter converter = new NumberConverter();
    System.out.println(converter.toEnglish(args[0]);
  }
}
```

You have now demonstrated TDD without mocking. In trying to practice TDD the mocking question will invariably come up. In order to demonstrate mocking, you can add some arbitrary business rule around the `toEnglish` method such as "All requests for numbers larger than 1000 must be logged to the large number department". Knowing that the large number department is hosted on another server that we don't want to have a dependency on we can test drive the interface and mock it out.

```
public class NumberConverterTest {
  // ..
  @Test public void theLargeNumberDepartmentIsNotifiedForLargeNumbers() {
     LargeNumberDepartment department = new MockLargeNumberDepartment(1000);
     NumberConverter converter = new NumberConverter(department);
     converter.toEnglish(1000);
     assertTrue(department.wasNotifiedWith(1000));
  }

  public static MockLargeNumberDepartment implements LargeNumberDepartment {

     private int valueRequested;

     public void MockLargeNumberDepartment(int threshhold) {
       this.threshold = threshold;
     }

     public int notificationThreshold() {
       return this.threshold;
     }

     public void largeNumberReceived(int value) {
       valueRequested = value;
     }

     public boolean wasNotifiedWith(int value) {
       assertEquals(value, valueRequested);
       return true;
     }
  }
}

// In NumberConverter.java
public class NumberConverter {
  public NumberConverter(LargeNumberDepartment department) {
    this.department = department;
  }

  public String toEnglish(int value) {
    if(value > department.notificationThreshold())
      department.largeNumberReceived(value);
    return convertIt(value);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all who replied. I have now written the program with your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with @Don Roby that the best thing to do is to actually write the tests first and see what falls out as an opportunity to mock something.

I see different elements to this program.

1. The 'main' executable part
2. The logic for processing the command line arguments
3. The algorithm for converting numbers to words
4. The mechanism for displaying the output

The first two may be trivially simple.  The third one may be complex enough to have it's own class.  The fourth one may be trivially simple to print out to the console, but if this were somehow a real program, there would potentially be some value in abstracting where it sends the answer so you could plug in other methods like writing to a file or a database or whatever, so it's not completely contrived to have an interface there with a concrete implementation that runs separately.

Comment: So you're saying that I should write an interface called say 'ConverterView' that has an abstract method called 'display'. Then mock this interface and in the unit tests pass it the System.out? So in the real program, the display could display to a webpage?

Comment: I have split my program up as follows: Converter class with main method. UserInput class+interface with to get input from user. Algorithm class+interface to do the conversion. Still haven't found a reason to mock something...

Comment: Well, if you're testing your main method, you don't test your Algorithm class and your UserInput class, you just ensure that they are getting called as you expect (with mocks) and then write separate unit tests for the Algorithm and separate unit tests for the UserInput.  That way if you have a lot that can go wrong with UserInput (bad format, broken pipe, whatever) you can test all those paths separately from the Algorithm logic, which has a completely different set of things that might go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking is typically useful only when you have some division of responsibilities between components, where the separation of concerns is "materialized" via an interface. Your problem as stated seems too narrow to illustrate that. One idea which would work would be to extend your problem, and design a Number Translator to multiple languages. In this case, I would expect a Strategy pattern to emerge, with a INumberTranslator interface exposing a string Translate(int number) method.

You could move fairly smoothly from TDD without mocks to TDD with mocks by first writing tests for the "translate to English" requirements, and then changing the requirements to " we need to support this in Spanish, too".